# Getting all upvotes for object with Acts_as_Votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-votable

How do I get the number of likes a user has made for all post accumulated with Acts_As_Votable

```
<%= user.posts.all.votes.size %>?? 
undefined method `votes' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x808a1d8>

resources :posts, except: [:edit, :update] do
    member do
      get 'like', to: 'posts#like'
      get 'dislike', to: 'posts#unlike'
    end
  end
```

I'm getting an error

Answer (score 0):

You have a collection of posts, not a single post element. My guess is that you want to do something like: `user.posts.all.map{|e| e.size}` . Be sure to tune your query to preload the posts. Perhaps something like: `user.includes(:posts)....`

Comment: Are you referring to the Acts_as_Votable gem with the method that referencing? I'm trying to find the extension method for counting all votes across post. For example: user.all_followers

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had to use summation. <%= user.posts.count(&:votes) %> to solve this issue.